# sys.exit() function in while loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I'm Working on Zed Shaw's learn python the hard way and I'm on Exercise 36. He wants us to make a game similar to that of ex 35. This is part of my code.

```
def ninja_dojo():
    print """
    You enter a big room.
    A ninja sits meditating between you and a door.
    How do you get past the ninja?
    """
    pass_ninja = False

    while True:

        move = raw_input('> ')

        if move == 'walk quietly':
            dead("As you pass the ninja, he springs up and guts you.")

        elif move == 'greet ninja':
            print "The ninja smiles and motions for you to pass."
            arcade()

        elif move == 'fight ninja':
            dead("As you step forward to make your move, the ninja throws a Shuriken               that slits your throat. You slowly bleed out.")

        else:
            dead("The ninja notices you and kills you, thinking you're an intruder. ooops.")
            exit(0)
```

When I run this and pass something that satisfies the else block, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/Anusha/Desktop/Anusha/Freshmore/Python/ex1.py", line 834, in <module>
    start()   File "/Users/Anusha/Desktop/Anusha/Freshmore/Python/ex1.py", line 829, in start
    ninja_dojo()   File "/Users/Anusha/Desktop/Anusha/Freshmore/Python/ex1.py", line 807, in ninja_dojo
    exit(0) SystemExit: 0
```

can someone explain this to me? why doesn't exit(0) work here? here is Zed's code, it works just fine.

```
  def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold.  How much do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if "0" in next or "1" in next:
        how_much = int(next)

    else:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")

    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)
    else:
        dead("Your greedy bastard!")
```

I have started my module with "from sys import exit: just like him.
For my while loop, if I use break in place of exit(0), it works perfectly. My question is why doesn't exit(0) work?
Thanks a ton in advance!!

Comment: In what way is that not working? Seems to do exactly what you've asked, raise an exception to exit the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.exit()` works by raising the `SystemExit` exception. If anything catches it or an ancestor, then the exception handler will run.

Comment: Thanks! When you say "the exception handler will run.", is that the error message that I receive?

Comment: It would, but I'm not familiar with the application or interpreter that would generate the traceback in that format.

Comment: Oh ok. I was using IDLE

Answer (score 0):

`sys.exit(code)` raises `SystemExit` exception. If you want to quit, you can use `break` or `return`